# Facing strange issue after compilation missing pub directory in all files paths CSS, JS etc

Tags: magento2

Magento2 I am facing a strange issue where my Frontend is broken. Missing pub directory in all CSS/JS/Images etc..

```
http://magento/static/version1621852367/frontend/theme/default/en_US/mage/calendar.css
```

This should be

```
http://magento/pub/static/version1621852367/frontend/theme/default/en_US/mage/calendar.css
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check "Base URL for Static View Files" and "Base URL for User Media Files" url under "Generel -> Web "

if you can not able to access adminpanel then search in database "core_config_data" table "base_static_url" and "base_media_url".
both filed should empty or

> base_static_url = your_store_url/pub/static
>
> base_media_url= your_store_url/pub/media